# How to read xml file correctly in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

I want  to read  config.xml  file   but  this  file  can  be  used  by several  processor  at  the same  time  and  to  prevent  this  action i  need  to use   fileLock, i  read  xml   by  this  code  but  it  isn't  in right  format  it  looks  like  this
How can  i  read  this xml  in  right   format?:

```
»¿<localAttributes>
<start>2017-09-07</start>
<runAs>true</runAs>
<makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
/localAttributes>
```

here  is  my  code (i  use  this code  inside  nifi  ecmascript processor p.s  i don't   wont to  use  extra  processors  like  getFile and etc..):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import  java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
  File file = new File("C://Users//user//Desktop//try2//nifi-1.3.0//1");
        String  content=" ";
        try {
            RandomAccessFile ini = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws");
            FileLock lock = ini.getChannel().lock();
            try {

                while (ini.read() != -1) {
                    content=+ini.readLine();
                }
            } finally {
                lock.release();
                ini.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FlowFile  flowFile=session.create();
        flowFile=session.putAttribute(flowFile,"filename","conf.xml");
        session.write(flowFile, {outputStream ->
            outputStream.write(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        } as OutputStreamCallback);
        session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read xml file in right format"? It is a text file, and you seem to be reading it as text after all, so why isn't *that* a right format?

Comment: I  mean  reading  without <<?  this

Comment: it  is  placed  at  the  first  line

Comment: If it's inside your file, you should fix the file, not your program.

Comment: iside  my xml   file     such  symbols  »¿  aren't  presented

Comment: In this case, you should look at your file encoding and use correct encoding when reading it.

Comment: Do  you mean  adding  utf  8  in   bufferdreader?

Comment: This isn't Groovy is it?

Comment: yes , it  is   groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is saved in UTF-8 with an optional Byte-Order-Mark (BOM) showing that it is UTF-8. But you use the default sytem charset to read it. In your case you execute this on Windows where the default encoding is ISO-8859-1 which results in the BOM being decoded as two characters.

While your code is not Groovy-like at all, if you insist on using `RandomAccessFile` to read the file, you need to use a `Reader` to be able to specify the encoding, e. g. something like

```
new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8")).readLine()
```

Comment: my  code  is  groovy  but  i want to  implement  this  logic  inside it , as  i know  i  can use anything ( which is  implemented in java )  in groovy

Comment: Do  you  think  that  i  should  make  it   another  way  in  groovy  code?

Comment: Well no, your code is Java and also runs as is under Groovy, but e. g. this would be more groovy and replace all your reading code, including my fix of your code, as the respective Groovy code contains encoding detection that recognizes the BOM: `def content = new File(/C:\Users\user\Desktop\try2\nifi-1.3.0\1/).text`

Comment: I wanted  to  use   file  lock,  thread  sleep and related  implementations   which  is spupported in  java  in   groovy  tha's  why  i  have  accepted   yoor   first  answer  i gurss   it  was  helpful ,

Comment: I know  about  it def content = new File(C://Users//user//Desktop//try2//nifi-1.3.0//1).getText()    but  i   guess  i  can't  use   file  lock  on  it.  that's  why  i    dno't  use   groovy logic  ,  by  the   way   is  there any native  implementation for  file  lock and   Thread.sleep  in  groovy?

Comment: And yes, there are Groovy variants of thread sleeping methods, those e. g. can wait for the specified time even if there are interrupts during waiting. The quesiton is whether you really have a valid use-case to use thread sleeping.

Comment: I think  i need   because  i  have  config  file  which  should   be  updated   by  several  processor (which  aren't  connected  neither  logically  no  phisically ) at  a  time and  i   want  to  prevent  it , as   i  want my   file  to   be  updated   by  only  one  processor  at a  time